# how to select date from dropdown calender using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have a dropdown calendar and I need to select a date from it using Selenium.
I'm using python as my scripting Language. I'm also new to this selenium.

Comment: Can you please post the HTML source code of dropdown calendar you need to select? Accurate answers need accurate info :)

Comment: rit now i don've acces to the application.if i get i'll post.

Answer (score 1):

For the following HTML:

```
<select id="edit-birthday-day" class="form-select" name="birthday[day]">
 <option selected="selected" value="">-</option>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

use you can use the following scripting in Python:

```
    sel.select("id=edit-birthday-day", "label=2")
```

Please also refer to [Selenium Documentation](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/0.8.0/reference.html):

```
select ( selectLocator,optionLocator )
Select an option from a drop-down using an option locator.
Option locators provide different ways of specifying options of an HTML Select element (e.g. for selecting a specific option, or for asserting that the selected option satisfies a specification). There are several forms of Select Option Locator.

label=labelPattern
matches options based on their labels, i.e. the visible text. (This is the default.)
label=regexp:^[Oo]ther
value=valuePattern
matches options based on their values.
value=other
id=id
matches options based on their ids.
id=option1
index=index
matches an option based on its index (offset from zero).
index=2
If no option locator prefix is provided, the default behaviour is to match on label.

Arguments:

selectLocator - an element locator identifying a drop-down menu
optionLocator - an option locator (a label by default)
```

Comment: What is the sel object in this context?  WebDriver or ...? Thanks!